# Represent some value along time with QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, symbology, representation

I would like to create a dynamic representation of a dataset along the time in QGIS.

I have my data in a layer and a table with a relation from one to many:

`TABLE_1      TABLE_2
id_city ---> id_city
city         year
             population`

My idea is to make some kind of *animation* that represent the values of population with a range of colors along the time.

To do that I've created a new layer with the geometry of every city duplicated as many times as years and the data of *TABLE 2*, but I have some doubts...

- Anyone knows if is there any way to do this representation with QGIS?
- Is it possible to do it just seting the relation and without a new layer with duplicated geometries?

I have tried the *Time manager plugin* of QGIS, but as long as i know it shows new geometries along the time, and does not show the same polygon with different values of population (in this case...).

Answer (score 4):

As far as I'm aware, there is no alternative to TimeManager and there you indeed need to duplicated the geometries.